# C++ Pattern Matching with FFT cross-correlation (Images)

Tags: c++, pattern-matching, image-recognition, fftw, cross-correlation

everyone I am trying to implement patter matching with FFT but I am not sure what the result should be (I think I am missing something even though a read a lot of stuff about the problem and tried a lot of different implementations this one is the best so far). Here is my FFT correlation function.

```
void fft2d(fftw_complex**& a, int rows, int cols, bool forward = true)
{
    fftw_plan p;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(cols, a[i], a[i], forward ? FFTW_FORWARD : FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        fftw_execute(p);
    }

    fftw_complex* t = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(rows * sizeof(fftw_complex));

    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        {
            t[i][0] = a[i][j][0];
            t[i][1] = a[i][j][1];
        }

        p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(rows, t, t, forward ? FFTW_FORWARD : FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        fftw_execute(p);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        {
            a[i][j][0] = t[i][0];
            a[i][j][1] = t[i][1];
        }
    }

    fftw_free(t);
}

int findCorrelation(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    BMP bigImage;
    BMP keyImage;
    BMP result;
    RGBApixel blackPixel = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    const bool swapQuadrants = (argc == 4);

    if (argc < 3 || argc > 4) {
        cout << "correlation img1.bmp img2.bmp" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (!keyImage.ReadFromFile(argv[1])) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (!bigImage.ReadFromFile(argv[2])) {
        return 1;
}
    //Preparations
    const int maxWidth = std::max(bigImage.TellWidth(), keyImage.TellWidth());
    const int maxHeight = std::max(bigImage.TellHeight(), keyImage.TellHeight());

    const int rowsCount = maxHeight;
    const int colsCount = maxWidth;

    BMP bigTemp = bigImage;
    BMP keyTemp = keyImage;

    keyImage.SetSize(maxWidth, maxHeight);
    bigImage.SetSize(maxWidth, maxHeight);

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; ++j) {
            RGBApixel p1;

            if (i < bigTemp.TellHeight() && j < bigTemp.TellWidth()) {
                p1 = bigTemp.GetPixel(j, i);
            } else {
                p1 = blackPixel;
            }

            bigImage.SetPixel(j, i, p1);

            RGBApixel p2;

            if (i < keyTemp.TellHeight() && j < keyTemp.TellWidth()) {
                p2 = keyTemp.GetPixel(j, i);
            } else {
                p2 = blackPixel;
            }

            keyImage.SetPixel(j, i, p2);
        }
    //Here is where the transforms begin
    fftw_complex **a = (fftw_complex**)fftw_malloc(rowsCount * sizeof(fftw_complex*));
    fftw_complex **b = (fftw_complex**)fftw_malloc(rowsCount * sizeof(fftw_complex*));
    fftw_complex **c = (fftw_complex**)fftw_malloc(rowsCount * sizeof(fftw_complex*));

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; ++i) {

        a[i] = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(colsCount * sizeof(fftw_complex));
        b[i] = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(colsCount * sizeof(fftw_complex));
        c[i] = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(colsCount * sizeof(fftw_complex));

        for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; ++j) {
            RGBApixel p1;

            p1 = bigImage.GetPixel(j, i);

            a[i][j][0] = (0.299*p1.Red + 0.587*p1.Green + 0.114*p1.Blue);
            a[i][j][1] = 0.0;

            RGBApixel p2;

            p2 = keyImage.GetPixel(j, i);

            b[i][j][0] = (0.299*p2.Red + 0.587*p2.Green + 0.114*p2.Blue);
            b[i][j][1] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    fft2d(a, rowsCount, colsCount);
    fft2d(b, rowsCount, colsCount);

    result.SetSize(maxWidth, maxHeight);

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; ++j) {
            fftw_complex& y = a[i][j];
            fftw_complex& x = b[i][j];

            double u = x[0], v = x[1];
            double m = y[0], n = y[1];

            c[i][j][0] = u*m + n*v;
            c[i][j][1] = v*m - u*n;

            int fx = j;
            if (fx>(colsCount / 2)) fx -= colsCount;

            int fy = i;
            if (fy>(rowsCount / 2)) fy -= rowsCount;

            float r2 = (fx*fx + fy*fy);

            const double cuttoffCoef = (maxWidth * maxHeight) / 37992.;
            if (r2<128 * 128 * cuttoffCoef)
                c[i][j][0] = c[i][j][1] = 0;
        }

    fft2d(c, rowsCount, colsCount, false);

    const int halfCols = colsCount / 2;
    const int halfRows = rowsCount / 2;

    if (swapQuadrants) {
        for (int i = 0; i < halfRows; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < halfCols; ++j) {
                std::swap(c[i][j][0], c[i + halfRows][j + halfCols][0]);
                std::swap(c[i][j][1], c[i + halfRows][j + halfCols][1]);
            }

        for (int i = halfRows; i < rowsCount; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < halfCols; ++j) {
                std::swap(c[i][j][0], c[i - halfRows][j + halfCols][0]);
                std::swap(c[i][j][1], c[i - halfRows][j + halfCols][1]);
            }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; ++j) {
            const double& g = c[i][j][0];
            RGBApixel pixel;

            pixel.Alpha = 0;
            int gInt = 255 - static_cast<int>(std::floor(g + 0.5));
            pixel.Red = gInt;
            pixel.Green = gInt;
            pixel.Blue = gInt;

            result.SetPixel(j, i, pixel);
        }


    BMP res;
    res.SetSize(maxWidth, maxHeight);

    result.WriteToFile("result.bmp");

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output[image: Result from calling the function]

Comment: Are you expecting something other than a patch of very high values where the pattern image's origin would be relative to the checked image if you aligned it on top of the checked image?

Comment: I am expection somethin like this https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2007/spring/cs481/lecture/03_29_fft_image.html as most of the code is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question would probably be more appropriately posted on another site like [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) (metaoptimize.com used to also be a good one, but it appears to be gone)

That said:

There's two similar operations you can perform with FFT: convolution and correlation.  Convolution is used for determining how two signals interact with each-other, whereas correlation can be used to express how similar two signals are to each-other.  Make sure you're doing the right operation as they're both commonly implemented throught a DFT.

For this type of application of DFTs you usually wouldn't extract any useful information in the fourier spectrum unless you were looking for frequencies common to both data sources or whatever (eg, if you were comparing two bridges to see if their supports are spaced similarly).

Your 3rd image looks a lot like the power domain; normally I see the correlation output entirely grey except where overlap occurred.  Your code definitely appears to be computing the inverse DFT, so unless I'm missing something the only other explanation I've come up with for the fuzzy look could be some of the "fudge factor" code in there like:

```
if (r2<128 * 128 * cuttoffCoef)
  c[i][j][0] = c[i][j][1] = 0;
```

As for what you should expect: wherever there are common elements between the two images you'll see a peak.  The larger the peak, the more similar the two images are near that region.

Some comments and/or recommended changes:

1) Convolution & correlation are not scale invariant operations.  In other words, the size of your pattern image can make a significant difference in your output.

2) Normalize your images before correlation.

When you get the image data ready for the forward DFT pass:

```
a[i][j][0] = (0.299*p1.Red + 0.587*p1.Green + 0.114*p1.Blue);
a[i][j][1] = 0.0;
/* ... */
```

How you grayscale the image is your business (though I would've picked something like `sqrt( r*r + b*b + g*g )`).  However, I don't see you doing anything to normalize the image.

The word "normalize" can take on a few different meanings in this context.  Two common types:

- normalize the range of values between 0.0 and 1.0
- normalize the "whiteness" of the images

3) Run your pattern image through an edge enhancement filter.  I've personally made use of [canny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector), [sobel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator), and I think I messed with a few others.  As I recall, canny was "quick'n dirty", sobel was more expensive, but I got comparable results when it came time to do correlation.  See [chapter 24](http://www.dspguide.com/ch24.htm) of the "dsp guide" book that's freely available online.  The whole book is worth your time, but if you're low on time then at a minimum chapter 24 will help a lot.

4) Re-scale the output image between [0, 255]; if you want to implement thresholds, do it after this step because the thresholding step is lossy.

My memory on this one is hazy, but as I recall (edited for clarity):

- You can scale the final image pixels (before rescaling) between [-1.0, 1.0] by dividing off the largest power spectrum value from the entire power spectrum
- The largest power spectrum value is, conveniently enough, the center-most value in the power spectrum (corresponding to the lowest frequency)
- If you divide it off the power spectrum, you'll end up doing twice the work; since FFTs are linear, you can delay the division until after the inverse DFT pass to when you're re-scaling the pixels between [0..255].
- If after rescaling most of your values end up so black you can't see them, you can use a solution to the ODE `y' = y(1 - y)` (one example is the sigmoid `f(x) = 1 / (1 + exp(-c*x) )`, for some scaling factor `c` that gives better gradations).  This has more to do with improving your ability to interpret the results visually than anything you might use to programmatically find peaks.

*edit* I said [0, 255] above.  I suggest you rescale to [128, 255] or some other lower bound that is gray rather than black.

Comment: I used this as reference for implementing my code https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2007/spring/cs481/lecture/03_29_fft_image.html but my output is totally different

Comment: What is more here is my code if you could give it a try I tried the things you say but it only gets worse :( http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=91248828035710455094 I am pretty stuck with this.

Comment: Unfortunately, the machine I have access to with a compiler is air-gapped from the internet.  I'd have to re-type the whole thing.  I'll skim it to see if I see anything that jumps out at me.  Back when I was first learning this material I used http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm.  It's not a long book, so I would suggest you read through it.

Comment: I posted here the edited code with some of the suggestions you gave me but the results aren't better :( http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159512/c-pattern-matching-with-fft-cross-correlation-images

Comment: Read through chapter 24 of that dspguide.com book.  One trick I forgot to mention is they recommend passing your pattern image through an edge enhancement filter.  This helps to emphasize the details you want it hit on.

Comment: The edge filter your professor is using seems weird.  Maybe I'm just not reading it carefully enough.  When I did stuff like this I got much clearer peaks than he gets in his write-up.  I suggest you get rid of his method.  His method is saying "if the magnitude of the frequency is too high, zero it", but an edge detection filter says "if the frequency itself is low, zero it" -- which has absolutely nothing to do with the magnitude of the frequency.

Comment: if you are talking about this  float r2 = (fx*fx + fy*fy); if (r2<128) c[i][j][0] = c[i][j][1] = 0; when i remove it i get just a black screen :(

Comment: As an example of what I mean: do your forward passes and convert to polar form.  Then on your pattern image, zero all of your low frequencies in a square shape around the center, ignoring what the actual value is, then do an inverse pass on the pattern image and render it (no correlation).  The result should be an image with a lot of details removed, mostly just edges left.  In practice you wouldn't actually do it in a square around the center, I'm just offering a quick'n dirty way to visualize what's happening.

Comment: I wanted to move to chat, but the domain is blocked for me so I can't access it.  Send me an email: phantall@gmail.com

Comment: i sended you an email